Are there any Madhwa Sadhus in Himalayas?
I want to know if there are any sadhus/yogis associated with Madhwa Sampradaya in Himalayas and Kashi etc..
Please dont suggest any mantra vrata or sadhana..just answer if you know any living Madhwa Guru in Himalayas..thanks

Well, there are Lord Ved Vyas, His disciples, and Shri Madhvacharya in His divine ashram. Why don't you honestly pray to them for a year? Shri Hari-Vayu Gurubhyo Namah! Jaya jaya jagatrANa, jagadoLage sutrANa, akhila guNa sadhdhAma madhvanAma!

Are you an Indian?

Are you a Madhwa Brahmin?

What is your age?

Yes I am Indian, Yes (though a former Advaitin and still trying to live up to my surname), will be 26. Debbie is a pen-name I use on stack exchange. If you ask for my real name, then sorry I will not tell you because that is nobody's business.

Now time for my questions.

Are you a Hindu by birth or belief?

I remember that you used to go by the name AryanInvader and that you commented on one of my questions. You said you were a dualist. Are you a Madhwa?

What is your age (year number, month number, and day number)?

Also, why did you post each question as a separate comment? Do you think I am some white-skinned Westerner who is trolling Hinduism Stack Exchange?

Yes brother I am a Madhwa.I cannot mention my birthdate here but I am 31 years old

No I just casually asked..

Hello brother, I was joking about the month and day number :)
